# Resize canvas to fit the image size and scale with FabricJs

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

After some research I saw merely the examples of fitting image to canvas. Is it possible to make it other way around and make an image source for the canvas, so when I load the image, Canvas is basically the loaded image and resized to the image scale and dimensions?

What I need is to draw rectangles over image. Rectangle position and size is important to me in relation to the image.

I am using FabricJS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy to do using [canvas.setWidth()](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#setWidth) and [canvas.setHeight()](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#setHeight) as soon as you know the image's dimensions.

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c")
const url = "https://via.placeholder.com/200x100"
const imgEl = document.createElement("img")
imgEl.src = url
imgEl.onload = () => {
  const img = new fabric.Image(imgEl)
  img.set({
    left: 50,
    top: 50,
    scaleX: 2,
    scaleY: 1.5
  })
  canvas.add(img)
  canvas.requestRenderAll()
  document.querySelector('#b').onclick = () => {
    canvas.setWidth(img.getScaledWidth())
    canvas.setHeight(img.getScaledHeight())
    img.set({
      left: 0,
      top: 0
    })
    img.setCoords()
    canvas.requestRenderAll()
  }
}
```

```css
#c {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.5/fabric.js"></script>
<button id="b">fit canvas to image</button>
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Is it possible (after resizing it to image dimensions) to make canvas fit and centered to the parent div?